# How to add extended attribute via VB to a data item

Tags: powerdesigner

I am trying to create a CDM by importing an excel spread sheet into PD via VBS.

1 - Load the spread sheet
2 - Create CDM
3 - Create the data items With extended attributes.

I can load the and create the CDM, and create the data items, as long as I dont have extended attributes, however I cant create extended attributes in VBS - but need to create the extended attributes in order to load the rest of the spread sheet. Any ideas.

Code currently looks like:

```
> Option Explicit
> 
> InteractiveMode = im_Dialog
> 
> Dim Model, objExcel, objWorkbook, intRow, LogFile, lobj, MyExa Set
> Model = ActiveModel Dim MyModel, t, r, sym set MyModel =
> CreateModel(PdCDM.Cls_Model,"DBMS=SYASA12")
> 

> 
> Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") Set objWorkbook =
> objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\ Models\09.
> Dictionary\DataDictionaryTestImport.xlsx")
> 
> intRow = 2
> 
> DIM Name, Stewards, LongDescription, ParentCategory,
> DomainSubCategory,  BusinessUnit, BusinessUnitArea,
> BusinessUnitDepartment, Calculations, DataOwner, ValidationRule,
> DataQualityBusinessRules, Format, SourceSystemName, 
> GoldenSourceSystem, ElementType DIM v_tp
> 
> 
> Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""    Name              = 
> objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value    Stewards       =  objExcel.Cells(intRow,
> 2).Value    LongDescription       =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value   
> ParentCategory    =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value   
> DomainSubCategory =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 5).Value   
> BusinessUnit      =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 6).Value   
> BusinessUnitArea          =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 7).Value   
> BusinessUnitDepartment    =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 8).Value   
> Calculations      =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 9).Value    DataOwner     = 
> objExcel.Cells(intRow, 10).Value    DataQualityBusinessRules  = 
> objExcel.Cells(intRow, 11).Value    ValidationRule    = 
> objExcel.Cells(intRow, 12).Value    Format        =  objExcel.Cells(intRow,
> 13).Value    SourceSystemName         =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 14).Value   
> GoldenSourceSystem    =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 15).Value   
> ElementType   =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 16).Value
>        Set t=MyModel.dataitems.CreateNew()
>        t.Name             =  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
>     CreateAttributes t
>       Logger LogFile, Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & " " & Time & " - Object: " & name
>        intRow = intRow + 1    loop
>        'Create Data Items For idx = 1 to 12
>     Next
>      
>       'Log file Sub Logger (LogFilename, LogText)     Dim fso     Dim LogFile         Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    Set
> LogFile = fso.OpenTextFile(LogFilename, 8, True)  LogFile.WriteLine
> LogText    End Sub
> 
> 
> Function CreateAttributes(t)  Dim attr  Set attr =
> t.CreateObject(Pdcdm.cls_Attribute)    t=MyModel.dataitems.CreateNew()
> attr.Name = "ID"  attr.Code = "ID"  attr.DataType = "int" 
> attr.Persistent = True  attr.PersistentCode = "ID" 
> attr.PersistentDataType = "I"  attr.PrimaryIdentifier = True  Set attr
> = t.CreateObject(Pdcdm.cls_Attribute)  attr.Name = "Name"  attr.Code = "Name"  attr.DataType = "String"  attr.Persistent = True 
> attr.PersistentCode = "NAME"  attr.PersistentDataType = "A30"
> 
>  CreateAttributes = True End Function
```

Comment: Your VBscript code has been a little messed up by SO editor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to set an extended attribute related to the `Sybase SQL Anywhere 12` DBMS that you picked.

You should write it as:

> obj.SetExtendedAttribute "SYASA12.CastDataType", value

I guess that if you don't specify the target code, it assumes that the extended attribute is defined in the current model, not in some external model/target.

.. in fact, to quote the "SAP PowerDesigner Scripting" (pdvbs.chm in the installation directory):

> Changes the values of an extended attribute, identified by its
>   qualified name - the name of the extended attribute prefixed by the
>   code of the GenerationTarget object on which it is defined. For
>   example: "MyGenerationTarget.MyExtendedAttribute".

In the shipped targets, this is written as `obj.SetExtendedAttribute "%CurrentTargetCode%.CastDataType", value` where `%CurrentTargetCode%` is replaced by the actual target code before the VBscript is prepared, and executed.

In case, the extended attribute is not of type text, you can use SetExtendedAttributeText to try, and use the automatic conversion from text to the actual attribute type.